# How to watch all properties of an object which is generated dynamically?

Tags: angularjs

Consider the snippet:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat = "value in array" >
            <td><input ng-model="formdata[value]" /></td>
            <td>{{value}}</td>
            <td>{{formdata[value]}}</td>
            <td>{{data}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {


        $scope.array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        $scope.$watch("formdata",
                               function() {
                                  // some code goes here    
                               }, true
        );
});
</script>
```

The ng-model for each row is generated dynamically as seen clearly.

```
formdata[1]
formdata[2]
formdata[3]
formdata[4]
formdata[5]
```

Now I want to put a watch on all the properties of this object(formdata). I did like above but the watch never gets fired.

Please suggest.

Comment: There is no formdata in this scope, so there's nothing to watch. The formdata is created inside a child scope, created by ng-repeat.

Comment: @JBNizet : Perfect, when I declare $scop.formdata = {} in the controller; the watch gets fired. I would be more than happy if you put that comment as an answer, because its really is an amazing answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't create formdata in the scope, so ng-repeat creates it, in its own child scope. And the formdata is thus not in your scope, and thus can't be watched.

I would start at 0 rather than 1, and initialize the array in the scope:

```
$scope.formdata = [];
```

Comment: Your comment/answer really came as a surprise to me, as I thought that you look more about Java & related technologies. The last answer which you gave to one of my questions was about volatile keyword. Simple, effective english language once again. Thank you so so much....